# VueJs2 using stores with components

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2

I am using vuejs 2.0 with vue-router and webpack.

I need to list items in a component using the session-store.js which is inside src/stores folder, but I am not able to read data from the store in App.vue and inside my components.

session-store.js

```
import $ from 'jquery'

var SessionStore = {
  state: {
    data: []
  },
  fetchSessionScheduleData: function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://www.myapi.com/items',
      success: function (response) {
        if (response.data) {
          SessionStore.state.data = response.data
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

App.vue

```
<script>
import SessionStore from './stores/session-store.js'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Test
  },
  data () {
    return {
      SessionStore: SessionStore.state
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData: function () {
      SessionStore.fetchSessionScheduleData()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

main.js

```
import './assets/css/materialize.css'
import './assets/css/oclock-styles.css'
import './assets/css/styles.css'

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

import Hello from './components/Hello.vue'
import Schedule from './components/Schedule.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Schedule },
  { path: '/foo', component: Hello },
  { path: '/schedule', component: Schedule }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for routes: routes
})

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Schedule.Vue

```
<template>
  <div v-once>
        <h4>{{ formatDate(index) }}</h4>
        <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="expandable">
          <session-schedule v-for="log in item" v-bind:item="log"></session-schedule>
        </ul>
      </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {

  name: 'Schedule',
  data () {
    return 'Hello'
  },
  methods: {
    formatDate (date) {
      var moment = require('moment')
      var now = moment(new Date())
      var sessionDate = moment(date, 'DD-MM-YYYY', true).format()
      var diff = now.diff(sessionDate, 'd')
      if (diff === 0) {
        return 'Today'
      } else if (diff === 1) {
        return 'Yesterday'
      } else {
        return date
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

How should I modify it in order to be able to fetch the data?
and how to call the session-schedule component from the schedule component?

Comment: I think problem is that you didn't export your store object/variable, so try this `export default var SessionStore = {// your code here}`

Comment: @belmin where should I do this?

Comment: In your session store file, so put export default just before var keyword

Comment: Or use vuex stores instead. Vuex is built to work with Vue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use **vue-resource**. (Two reasons: no jQuery, designed for vue). 
In my application, I also use **vuex** which you don't need I guess however the vue-resource would look like this.

in bootstrap.js required by app.js (alternative for main.js) I have:

```
window.Vue = require('vue')
require('vue-resource')
```

*point: require of vue-resource adds `http` into `Vue` (js is so random)*

```
Vue.http.options.root = '//localhost:8000/api/v1'
```

Then in api/devices.js there is:

```
export function getDevices() {
  Vue.http.get('devices').then(response => {
    console.log(response)
  }, response => {
    console.log(response.status)
  })
}
```

*Keep an eye on the url slashes because vue-resource will use the root only when you don't write slash before the relative one and also not after root.

Finally in app.js (main.js) there will be something like that:

```
require('./bootstrap')

import http from 'vue'
import * as api from 'api/devices'

Vue.config.devtools = true
Vue.config.silent = false

new Vue({
  api,
  http,
  el: '#app',
  created() {
    console.log(this.api.getDevices())
  }
})
```

In child components you would access api as this.$api

*Maybe I wrote something wrong. This is just an example of how it works. I am not a vue pro ...yet :D Good luck. Btw, if you decide for vue-resource, check their examples coz I've shown you only the console.logs*